# Transform address string to (new) address entity before persisting data to database using a Symfony DataTransformer

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have a problem defining a special kind of form using Symfony2 3.3.

### General description of the problem:

Storing postal address data in a flexible and clean way with reduced duplicates is a difficult task, because there are so many combinations of address components like street, streetnumber, zipcode, locality, county, country etc. possible. There's no standardized international address format, 'address composition' differs among the countries. Besides that, data entered by users often contains typing errors.

Examples:

```
Platzl 9, 80331 Munic, Germany
221B Baker Street, London, United Kingdom
3-1 Kōkyogaien, Chiyoda-ku, Tōkyō-to 100-0002, Japan
```

Because address components vary between almost all countries (in Germany for example, 'county' is of no real interest, whereas in other countries it is needed for mailing purposes), I do not want to use a form with separate fields for every address component. Life would be much easier if there existed a standard address form that covers ALL countries ;-)

As there is none, I want to implement a form with only one single 'address string' text field like Google Maps' address search field. This should give more flexibility to the user and make it easier for him to enter his (international) address.

### Idea:

I'd like to use a data transformer to transform the address string into an address object, so its values can be validated (e.g. checked for an already existing matching address) and persisted into the database. My address table has 5 columns at the moment (street, streetnumber, zipcode, locality and country), other columns may be added to the model later. In order to get the components out of an address string, I use a web based 'Geodata address API'. This way, the address components come in a standardized form and therefore - as additional bonus - I can check for duplicates easily. The good thing is that variations in spelling or typing errors in the address string do not result in address duplicates, because the API returns 'standardized' address component values where typing errors are removed.

### Workflow, when a user submits the 'address' form:

-> see comments of file 'AddressEntityToAddressStringTransformer.php' in the sources below for further details

- Check for empty address string value and add a form error when value is empty
- The address string is sent to the API
- If a technical problem (e.g. timeout) or a parsing error occurs, an error message has to be added to the form
- If the API returns an address object as result, check if a record with the same data already exists in the database table
- If data already exists, add an error to the form. The value that is shown in the address string field should then be a composition of the returned standardized values, so typing errors are removed
- If data does not exist in the database, create a new address entity object and persist it

### Problem:

First of all, I'm not sure if using a data transformer is the right way to implement such a solution, because in the examples that I found in the documentation and other tutorials only already existing data seems to be transformed into another kind of '(visual) representation'. For my solution, also new address objects (not yet existing in a database table) have to be created (+validated and persisted).

With the sources I added to this post, I get the following result when submitting a new address (please have a look to the attached screenshot of the debug toolbar):

[Screenshot of web debug toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYiT8.jpg)

The form object (dumped in AddressController.php) has a child form named 'address' (upper red box in the screenshot) containing the standardized values as 'modelData' (green box in the screenshot), but the 'modelData' of the actual address form (type = 'Address', lower red box in the screenshot) is empty. Whatever I tried, I never got the transformed data into the 'modelData' object of the $form object. As a result, a new but empty 'Address' entity is persisted to the database table so the table columns contain NULL values.

I think I'm still missing a little 'something', but I don't know what. That's why I need your help ;-)

If a data transformer is not suitable for realizing what I need: Is there another 'Symfony way' for solving my problem?

Here are the PHP sources that I have so far:

src/AppBundle/Controller/AddressController.php (nothing special here...)

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Entity\Address;
//use ...

/**
 * Address controller.
 *
 * @Route("/{_locale}/address")
 */
class AddressController extends Controller
{
    // ...

    /**
     * Creates a new address entity.
     *
     * @Route("/new", name="address_new")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function newAction(Request $request)
    {
        $address = new Address();
        $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\Type\AddressType', $address);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
dump($form);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
dump($address);
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($address);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('address_show', array('id' => $address->getId()));
        }

        return $this->render('address/new.html.twig', array(
            'address' => $address,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }

    // ...
}
```

src/AppBundle/Entity/Address.php

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use AppBundle\Validator\Constraints as AddressAssert;

/**
 * Address
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="address")
 * @ORM\Entity
 ' @AddressAssert\AddressUniqueConstraint()
 */
class Address
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="street", type="string", length=255, precision=0, scale=0, nullable=true, unique=false)
     */
    private $street;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="housenumber", type="string", length=255, precision=0, scale=0, nullable=true, unique=false)
     */
    private $housenumber;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="zipcode", type="string", length=255, precision=0, scale=0, nullable=true, unique=false)
     */
    private $zipcode;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="locality", type="string", length=255, precision=0, scale=0, nullable=true, unique=false)
     */
    private $locality;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="country", type="string", length=255, precision=0, scale=0, nullable=true, unique=false)
     */
    private $country;

    // getter and setter methods
}
```

app/config/services.yml

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false
    address_type:
        class: AppBundle\Form\Type\AddressType
        tags:
            - { name: form.type }
    address_string_type:
        class: AppBundle\Form\Type\AddressStringType
        tags:
            - { name: form.type }
```

src/AppBundle/Form/Type/AddressType.php

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class AddressType extends AbstractType
{
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('address', AddressStringType::class)
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'mapped' => false,
        ));
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'appbundle_address';
    }
}
```

src/AppBundle/Form/Type/AddressStringType.php

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use AppBundle\Form\DataTransformer\AddressEntityToAddressStringTransformer;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;

class AddressStringType extends AbstractType
{
    private $transformer;

    public function __construct(AddressEntityToAddressStringTransformer $transformer)
    {
        $this->transformer = $transformer;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->addViewTransformer($this->transformer)
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'invalid_message' => 'Error :-(',
            'mapped' => false,
        ));
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return TextType::class;
    }
}
```

src/AppBundle/Form/DataTransformer/AddressEntityToAddressStringTransformer.php

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Form\DataTransformer;

use Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\TransformationFailedException;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use AppBundle\Entity\Address;
use AppBundle\Validator\AddressValidator;

class AddressEntityToAddressStringTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    /**
     * Transforms a non-standardized address string into a standardized address string
     *
     * @param  string $adrObjStandardized
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function transform($adrObjStandardized)
    {
        if ($adrObjStandardized === null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        $street_housenumber_str = trim($adrObjStandardized->getStreet().' '.$adrObjStandardized->getHousenumber());
        $zipcode_locality_str = trim($adrObjStandardized->getZipcode().' '.$adrObjStandardized->getLocality());
        $country_str = trim($adrObjStandardized->getCountry());
        $tmp_arr = array($street_housenumber_str, $zipcode_locality_str, $country_str);
        $tmp_arr = array_diff($tmp_arr, array(''));
        $adrStrStandardized = implode(', ', $tmp_arr);

        //$adrStrStandardized = 'Platzl 9, 80331 Munic, Germany';

        return $adrStrStandardized;
    }

    /**
     * Transforms an address string to an address object
     * If a matching address already exists in the address table, return it. When creating a new entry, AddressUniqueConstraint will later tell us 'Address already exists.'
     * If no address in the address table matches, return a new address object to be persisted into the address table
     *
     * @param  string $adrStrNotStandardized
     * @return object
     * @throws TransformationFailedException (if address could not be standardized by address validation service (via an API))
     */
    public function reverseTransform($adrStrNotStandardized)
    {
        // TODO: Implement workflow as follows:
        // 1. Try to standardize data by sending the address string to an address validation service (API)
        // 1.1. If standardizing was successful
        //   1.1.1. Look for an already existing record in the database table 'address'
        //     1.1.1.1. If address in table 'address' matches, return it
        //     1.1.1.2. If NO address in table 'address' matches, create new Address object containing standardized data and return it
        // 1.2. If standardizing was NOT successful
        // 1.2.1. Throw TransformationFailedException

        $validator = new AddressValidator();
        try
        {
            // 1. Try to standardize data by sending the address string to an address validation service (API)
            $standardized_data = $validator->validateAddressFromString($adrStrNotStandardized);

            $addr_data = array(
                'street' => $standardized_data['street'],
                'housenumber' => $standardized_data['housenumber'],
                'zipcode' => $standardized_data['zipcode'],
                'locality' => $standardized_data['locality'],
                'country' => $standardized_data['country'],
            );
        }
        catch (\Exception $e) // 1.2. Standardizing was NOT successful
        {
            // 1.2.1. Throw TransformationFailedException
            throw new TransformationFailedException(
                'Die Adress-Daten konnten nicht standardisiert werden.'
            );
        }

        // 1.1. We are still here, so standardizing was successful

        // 1.1.1. Look for an already existing record in the database table 'address'
        $address = $this->em
            ->getRepository(Address::class)
            ->findOneBy($addr_data)
        ;

        if ($address === NULL)
        {
            // 1.1.1.2. If NO address in table 'address' matches, create new Address object containing standardized data and return it
            $new_addr_obj = new Address();

            $new_addr_obj->setStreet($addr_data['street']);
            $new_addr_obj->setHousenumber($addr_data['housenumber']);
            $new_addr_obj->setZipcode($addr_data['zipcode']);
            $new_addr_obj->setLocality($addr_data['locality']);
            $new_addr_obj->setCountry($addr_data['country']);

            return $new_addr_obj;
        }
        else
        {
            // 1.1.1.1. If address in table 'address' matches, return it
            return $address;
        }
    }
}
```

src/AppBundle/Validator/Constraints/AddressUniqueConstraint.php

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class AddressUniqueConstraint extends Constraint
{
    public $message_already_exists = 'Address already exists.';
    public $message_invalid_form_data = 'Invalid form data.';

    public function getTargets()
    {
        return self::CLASS_CONSTRAINT;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function validatedBy()
    {
        return AddressUniqueConstraintValidator::class;
    }
}
```

src/AppBundle/Validator/Constraints/AddressUniqueConstraintValidator.php

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use AppBundle\Entity\Address;

class AddressUniqueConstraintValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManagerInterface
     */
    protected $em;

    /**
     * Construct
     * @param EntityManagerInterface $entityManager
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->em = $entityManager;
    }

    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        if (!$value instanceof Address)
        {
            $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message_invalid_form_data)
                ->addViolation();
        }

        $search = array('street' => $value->getStreet(), 'housenumber' => $value->getHousenumber(), 'zipcode' => $value->getZipcode(), 'locality' => $value->getLocality(), 'country' => $value->getCountry());

        $adresses = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Address')->findBy($search);

        if ($adresses && count($adresses) > 0)
        {
            $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message_already_exists)
                ->addViolation();
        }
    }
}
```